# VB.Net Textbox MaxLength

Tags: vb.net, textbox, maxlength

```js
Private Sub txtCaptcha_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtCaptcha.KeyPress
    If Char.IsLower(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Then
        Dim pos As Integer = txtCaptcha.SelectionStart
        txtCaptcha.Text = txtCaptcha.Text & Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)
        txtCaptcha.SelectionStart = pos + 1
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

after i use this event with textbox maxlength is dont work

how to make this code with maxlength 6 character ?

Comment: Define 'dont work'.  Any error message or exception?  What have you done to test that it doesn't work?

Comment: **It can convert to upper but maxlength is not 6 char**

Comment: Is it TextArea control?

Comment: nope this is textbox not multi line

Comment: After `Dim pos As Integer = ...` just add `If pos >= 6 Then Return` ???!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
Private Sub txtCaptcha_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtCaptcha.KeyPress
    If txtCaptcha.MaLength = txtCaptcha.Text.Length Then
        e.Handled = true
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'For Ctrl+V
    If AscW(e.KeyChar) = 22 Then
        Dim strPaste As String = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText() & txtCaptcha.Text
        If strPaste.Length > txtCaptcha.MaLength Then
            strPaste = strPaste.Substring(0, txtCaptcha.MaLength)
            txtCaptcha.Text = strPaste
            e.Handled = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Char.IsLower(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Then
        Dim pos As Integer = txtCaptcha.SelectionStart
        txtCaptcha.Text = txtCaptcha.Text & Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)
        txtCaptcha.SelectionStart = pos + 1
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently MaxLength is only for User-Input. That makes sense because your text box could get data from a bound datasource and you would truncate the existing data.

If you do

```
textBox1.Text = "something"
```

via code this is still allowed.

I suggest you change your routine to

```
    If txtCaptcha.Text.Length < txtCaptcha.MaxLength AndAlso (Char.IsLower(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)) Then
        Dim pos As Integer = txtCaptcha.SelectionStart
        txtCaptcha.Text = txtCaptcha.Text & Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)
        txtCaptcha.SelectionStart = pos + 1
        e.Handled = True
    End If
```

this will not handle the input if MaxLength is reached but the control will intercept the input and provide an error sound just as every TextBox with MaxLength set.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize controls and variables in `form load` then the code to set the `MaxLength` for a text box in form_load as follows

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txtCaptcha.MaxLength = 6
End Sub
```

Comment: @ ชม้อยศรี มีดีที่แวตา : I given the code to set the max length for a text box, but it will not solve your problem. so may i know what you are trying to achieve through your code?